# HTML/CSS Navigation bar dropdown doesn't display in a list format

Tags: html, css, navbar, dropdown

http://codepen.io/josterberg/pen/LxEZMy

```
<header>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav" id="navigationBar">
                <li class="nav-item-align-left"><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item-align-left"><a class="active" href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item-align-left"><a class="active" href="page3.html">Page 3</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item-align-left dropdown">
                    <a class="dropbtn">Account</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#">Settings</a>
                        <a href="#">Logout</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="icon">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="toggleResponsiveNav()">☰</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/all.js"></script>
            <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

As you can see, my dropdown for Account isn't going downward-- it's going to the left. What should I modify in my CSS that would change this behavior to make my downdrop go down instead of left?

Comment: use display: block !important; on .dropdown-content a {} your ul.nav li a is setting display to inline;

Comment: @Bosc thank you! This worked!

Comment: @Jordan I strongly discourage the use of `!important` because it was intended to be used by _user_ stylesheets in order to override site styles. Instead of using !important, make your selector more specific so it overrides the `display: inline` -- for example, I added `.nav li.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content a {
    display: block;
}` and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use bootstrap navbar you need to include the bootstrap js file as well:

```
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Take a look at this plunker:

http://embed.plnkr.co/kfUPcF/

Comment: I'm not using bootstrap, take a look at the codepen CSS.

Comment: @JordanOsterberg if you are not using bootstrap what is that function toggleResponsiveNav defined?

Comment: Whoops! Forgot to add that to the codepen, go check it now.

Comment: @JordanOsterberg it is showing a dropdown with list format now that you have added that. what do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I recommend you to change the .dropdown-content to

```
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #282828;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

If that doesn't work, you can always do `<br>` or `<hr>`, but that should work.
Remember that some browsers like Chrome, Firefox and Opera require to refresh the CSS code to load updated (or use private navigation) :P

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you need to use

```
class = "nav-item-align-left"
```

every single time. Just write in your CSS:

```
li {
  float: left;
}
```

In ul.nav, delete float: left; So it would look like:

```
ul.nav {
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #282828;
}
```

Delete ul.nav in ul.nav li a, so it would look like

```
li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: "SF UI Display Light", serif;
}
```

Instead of  ul.nav li a {...}

Change the color in dropbtn and .dropdown-content to white

Comment: In a few of the elements in the actual project I'm using these classes. I modified the code to make it generic and not tied to this project.

Comment: @JordanOsterberg Ok, if you want, you can have it in your code. Then just change the rest like I described above. Because it is really not that good, or highly recommended, to use !important